# System of equations with radicals: $2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}y^2}$ and $2\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^4}{3}+4} = 1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

> Solve the system of equations (in $\mathbb R$):
>   $$\begin{matrix}
> 2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}y^2}
> \\
> 2\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^4}{3}+4}
> =
> 1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}x^2}
> \end{matrix}.$$

This is from an older question, which was closed and deleted because of lack of context. (Here is [link for users who can see deleted questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290369/solve-the-system-of-equations/).) I will post my solution below - so I hope this time the question will not be closed for the lack of effort.

I found the system not too easy and somewhat interesting. (Of course I might have missed some straightforward way to the solution.) I'd be glad to see some other methods to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, you will have solution corresponding to $x=\pm y$. Now, if you expand the last equation, you have (if $x \geq 0$),$$-\frac{37 x^4}{12}+3 \sqrt{6} x^3+9 x^2+2 \sqrt{6} x-63=0$$ To get rid of the $\sqrt{6}$'s, define $x=\sqrt{6} z$ and the equation becomes $$-111 z^4+108 z^3+54 z^2+12 z-63=0$$ By inspection $z=1$ is a solution. Making the long division let you with $$-111 z^3-3 z^2+51 z+63=0$$ where $z=1$ is solution again. Another division and arrive to $$-111 z^2-114 z-63=0$$ which does not show real solutions.

So, the real solutions are all possible combinations of $(\pm \sqrt{6},\pm \sqrt{6})$

Answer (score 2):

From my answer to the deleted question:

The real solutions are $x=\pm \sqrt{6}$, $y = \pm \sqrt{6}$. There are also complex solutions.

I found this using Maple's "solve" command. A somewhat more "hands-on" approach:

```
> with(Groebner):
> eqs:= [s^4-x^4/3 - 4,t^2-3/2*y^2,u^4-y^4/3-4,
       v^2-3/2*x^2,2*s-1-t,2*u-1-v];
> G:=Basis(eqs,plex(s,t,u,v,x,y));
> factor(G[1]);
```

$$ \left( 1369\,{y}^{4}+660\,{y}^{2}+15876 \right)  \left( 
12065393290011975315218089\,{y}^{24}+31241483903922756527916216\,{y}^{
22}+1916822411606153357786575368\,{y}^{20}+
2366873160958375355737537632\,{y}^{18}+108410617754815247626287499632
\,{y}^{16}+77702138286145060148486883072\,{y}^{14}+
3076294432635247223638434223872\,{y}^{12}+
977270871111943893941425093632\,{y}^{10}+
46998177944708847603452419729152\,{y}^{8}+
1724702245845492185473755174912\,{y}^{6}+
369903763273618971503529112700928\,{y}^{4}-
28583510894171781210603713470464\,{y}^{2}+
1174425086245411511666388854083584 \right)  \left( {y}^{2}-6 \right) ^
{2}
 $$

The first factor obviously has no real roots, the last has $y = \pm \sqrt{6}$. For the middle factor:

`> sturm(sturmseq(op(2,%),y),y,-infinity,infinity)`;

$$0$$

So there are no real roots there either.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, we can assume that $x,y\ge0$. (Notice that all exponents are even. We can then add signs to get the remaining solutions.)

So our equations are changed to

$$2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}y\tag{1}$$
$$2\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\tag{2}$$

If we subtract the two equations, we get (1)-(2):
$$2\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}-\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^4}{3}+4}\right)=y-x.\tag{3}$$
Notice that the function $x\mapsto\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}$ is increasing.

So for $x>y$ the LHS is positive and the RHS is negative. Similarly, for $y<x$ the signs of the two expressions are opposite.

So we can only find a real solution for $x=y$, which gives us
$$2\sqrt[4]{\frac{x^4}{3}+4}=1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\tag{4}$$

From this we get
$$16\left(\frac{x^4}{3}+4\right)=\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}x\right)^4\tag{5}$$

This is a [quartic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation). In theory, this can be done by hand, but it will be very probably quite messy. WolframAlpha returns [this](http://preview.tinyurl.com/p76nd9d). (One of the solution, according to WA, is $\sqrt6$.)